# Trying to set Knitr 'document' output hook results in code chunk line breaks being lost

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I've been reading all the documentation and examples I can find for Knitr's [output hooks](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#output_hooks) for editing the output of the document.

I'm using Knitr to process a .Rmd file, which looks like this:

> [SOME_SHORTCODE_TO_BE_REPLACED] (I eventually want this to be replaced by Knitr when it parses the document)
>
> ````
> ```{r echo=TRUE, eval=FALSE} 
>
> data1 <- rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 10)
>
> data2 <- rnorm(10, mean = 2, sd = 2)
>
> model <- lm(data1 ~ data2)
>
> summary(model) 
> ```
> ````

If I run

```
opts_chunk$set(tidy = FALSE)
knit(filename, output = outputFilename.markdown)
```

on the file, it renders (correctly) like this:

> [SOME_SHORTCODE_TO_BE_REPLACED] (I eventually want this to be replaced by Knitr when it parses the document)
>
> ```r
>
> data1 <- rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 10)
>
> data2 <- rnorm(10, mean = 2, sd = 2)
>
> model <- lm(data1 ~ data2)
>
> summary(model)
>
> ```

*However,* if I do anything to **set the knit_hook "document"** (which goes through the full document after it's parsed), the **line breaks and code fences (```) in my code are deleted:**

```
# As I understand, this *should* be identical to Knitr's default for the document hook, which is to just do:
# knit_hook$set(document = identity)

knit_hooks$set(document = function(x) {
    x
})
# (Then re-knit the file using the commands above)
```

Result:

> [SOME_SHORTCODE_TO_BE_REPLACED] (I eventually want this to be replaced by Knitr when it parses the document)
>
> data1 <- rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 10)data2 <- rnorm(10, mean = 2, sd = 2)model <- lm(data1 ~ data2)summary(model)

I've seen several examples, including one from Yihui [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knitr/Pf8yx7My01s), that lead me to think that setting the document hook and just having it give back `x` shouldn't do anything different than its default. What am I missing here?

Eventually, I'd like to set the document hook to use `gsub()` to replace the shortcode in the document with other code. But this issue with line breaks and code fences is confusing me in the meantime.

I'd be grateful for any advice on how to retain those line breaks and code fences when changing the document hook!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set up the hook function *inside* the Rmd file. If you do it before `knit()`, you must call `render_markdown()` first.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying to set the hook options in a separate file without importing it as a "child" code chunk. I ended up adding this to the top of my document, and everything works: ```{r LoadSupportOptions, child='Support_Knitr_Options.R'}
```