# Append text with knit_hooks in Rmd to Md

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

My aim is to append some dynamic text at the very end of md file during Rmd to md conversion. So I'm using knitr hooks as shown below.

```
---
title: "A title"
excerpt: "Excerpt"
output:
  md_document:
    pandoc_args: ["--wrap=none"]
    variant: gfm+footnotes
    preserve_yaml: TRUE
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
  knitr::knit(inputFile);
  txt <- "hello";
  prev_doc_hook <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("document");
  knitr::knit_hooks$set(document = function(x) {prev_doc_hook(append(x, txt))});
 })
date: "2021/03/07"
---
```

**Problem** - As per above code, the output md file is well formatted but the txt variable is not appended.

However, if `knitr::knit(inputFile);` is used after `knitr::knit_hooks$set(document = function(x) {prev_doc_hook(append(x, txt))});`, the text (hello) is appended, but the code chunks in the output md file does not have code fences (not well-formatted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268584/trying-to-set-knitr-document-output-hook-results-in-code-chunk-line-breaks-bei).

The correct approach is to use `knitr::knit(inputFile);` after `knitr::knit_hooks$set`. For the code formatting of code-fences, add `render_markdown();` before calling `knit_hooks`.

So the correct code will be -

```
---
title: "A title"
excerpt: "Excerpt"
output:
  md_document:
    pandoc_args: ["--wrap=none"]
    variant: gfm+footnotes
    preserve_yaml: TRUE
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
  txt <- "hello";
  render_markdown(); # This is the modified line
  prev_doc_hook <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("document");
  knitr::knit_hooks$set(document = function(x) {prev_doc_hook(append(x, txt))});
  knitr::knit(inputFile)
 })
date: "2021/03/07"
---
```